# How to show Result from combined two tables by hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables in mysql.

**Table tabA:** { id, column1, column2}

**Table tabB:** {id, column1, column2}

Sql query: SELECT a.column1, a.column2, b.column2 FROM tabA a, tabB b WHERE a.id = b.id

How can I process the query result to display the values in the console?

Comment: Describe what console you are trying to see the query results in. Which tool have you been using?

Comment: I'm trying to display the result in the eclipse console through System.out.println (...); ,

but do not know how to process the result from the statement: 
List <T> list = query.list ();

Comment: If i using two tables in sql query i need create a class which will contains the fields from both tables(for type T in List declaration)?